# PostSharp Field Interception to Encrypt and Decrypt

Tags: encryption, field, postsharp, interception

Using PostSharp I would like to do Encryption/Decryption on Field Interception

I have a Class

```
public class guestbookentry
  {       
    [Encryption]  // This Attribute has to Encrypt and Decrypt
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string GuestName { get; set; }       
  }
```

I am saving the object in Azure Tables. Only particular Field has to be get En/Decrypt.

PostSharp Attribute on Field Interception

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PostSharp;
using PostSharp.Aspects;
using EncryptionDecryption;
using PostSharp.Serialization;
using PostSharp.Aspects.Advices;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

namespace GuestBook_Data
{
[Serializable]
public class EncryptionAttribute : LocationInterceptionAspect 
{      
    [MulticastPointcut(Targets = MulticastTargets.Field, Attributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance)]
    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        base.OnSetValue(args);
        if (args.Value != null)
        {             
            MD5CryptoServiceExample objMD5Encrypt = new MD5CryptoServiceExample();
            args.Value = objMD5Encrypt.Encrypt(args.Value.ToString()).Replace(" ", "+");
            args.ProceedSetValue();
        } 
    }

    public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        base.OnGetValue(args);
        if (args.Value != null)
        {              
            MD5CryptoServiceExample objMD5Encrypt = new MD5CryptoServiceExample();
            args.Value = objMD5Encrypt.Decrypt(args.Value.ToString()); //objMD5Encrypt.Decrypt(args.Value.ToString());
            args.ProceedGetValue();
        }
    } 
}
}
```

Problem is
 1. Successive Encryption and Decryption happens which is difficult to handle.

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

Note, that calling `base.OnSetValue(args)` is the same as calling `args.ProceedSetValue()`, and calling `base.OnGetValue(args)` is the same as calling `args.ProceedGetValue()`. This means that you're calling the *proceed* methods twice in each of your handlers.

What you need to do is to call `args.ProceedGetValue()` at the start of the `OnGetValue` to read the encrypted value, and call `args.ProceedSetValue()` at the end of the `OnSetValue` to save the encrypted value.

```
public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
{
    args.ProceedGetValue();
    if (args.Value != null)
    {
        args.Value = // decrypt
    }
}

public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
{
    if (args.Value != null)
    {
        args.Value = // encrypt
    }
    args.ProceedSetValue();
}
```

Also, you don't need to apply the `[MulticastPointcut]` attribute. It's used when developing composite aspects as described in [Developing Composite Aspects](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/complex-aspects).